# Pig Latin: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045

Tags: apache-pig

```
M = LOAD '/apps/hive/warehouse/hsfawtbx9000_archive.db/fds_audit_record_master_text' using PigStorage(',')
     AS(id:int,audit_action:chararray,userid:chararray,audit_time:datetime,record_type:chararray,record_identifier:double,master_record_type:chararray,master_record_identifier:double,record_display_id:chararray);
A = FILTER M BY (audit_time IS NOT NULL);
F = GROUP A BY ToDate((audit_time,'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

> 2015-12-27 15:53:45,981 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 1045:  Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate as multiple or none of them
>   fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Not sure why it is complaining.

Comment: When I use chararray type during LOAD, I get error 6017 when doing ToDate which I tried earlier. [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 6017: JobID: job_1447970573826_0481 Reason: Job failed!

Comment: First of all, could you confirm that there are no additional parenthesis when you are grouping?

Answer (score 0):

Todate() function will accept only "string" (chararray or byterarray) or "Long millis" as input

see this https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ToDate.html

Looks like your input audit_time:datetime is in Datetime format

Comment: When I use chararray, I get error 6017 which I tried earlier.  [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 6017: JobID: job_1447970573826_0481 Reason: Job failed!